# What does this series do: $\ln((2n+1)/(2n-1))$? (Converges or Diverges?)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

what this series do when n is going to be a large number.

ln((2n+1)/(2n-1)) when n is tending to infinity?

I used integral test, ratio test, comparison test and ...
what do you think about this series ???

Answer (score 6):

The series diverges! To see why, look at a partial sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}{\log\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n-1}\right)} = \log\frac{3}{1} + \log\frac{5}{3} + \cdots + \log\frac{2N+1}{2N-1} \\ = \log\frac{2N+1}{1} \\ = \log(2N+1)$$
which diverges.

Comment: how the first line implies the second line: log (2N+1)/1?

Comment: Use log properties and you see things cancels out.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$\frac {2n+1}{2n-1}=1+\frac {2}{2n-1} $$

$$\ln (1+\frac {2}{2n-1})\sim \frac {2}{2n-1}\;\;(n\to+\infty) $$

$\sum \frac {2}{2n-1}$ diverges thus your series diverges as positive equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

What happens to the terms in the series as n gets large? In the limit, the argument of the log tends to a constant value, call it c (you have to find it!)

Now that means you end up adding lots of copies of ln(c), infinitely many times. It should be obvious that this cannot converge to a finite answer.

*Edit: in this case c=1 and the terms do tend to zero as pointed out in the comments*

Comment: I believe that the limit of the $\ln((2x+1)/(2x-1))$ is zero

Comment: You are quite right - I had not seen the factor of 2 in the denominator. Post edited.